# How do I fix duplicate entries in database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, connection

i am having an issue with my code...im not sure what is causing it to be entered in twice in my database. the information inputted in the form is inserted in the database and then there is another entry below it but it is empty. it happens everytime the form is submitted. how do i fix it?

```
<?php
// form data //

$id = $_POST['id'];
$joined = date("Y/m/d");
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

// Create connection
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("db"); //select database


    //register into database


    $sql = mysql_query("

    INSERT INTO table VALUES 
 ('','$joined','$uname','$email')       
    ");

echo "thanks for signing up!";

?>
```

Comment: why you put your first value as blank?

Comment: Try closing the connection right after the insert. (Note: That is the very least of your problems with a query like that.)

Comment: i tried to remove the blank value for 'id' in the code but it won't even insert into the database anymore, so i kept it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this might have something to do with `.htaccess` redirect the second time which might explain the insert but with blank values. Please verify that the values are not null before inserting. This will keep your blank values away.

Also, check your `.htaccess` and fix whatever problem is causing it to hit your page twice.

Comment: how do i check the .htaccess page? i changed all the null values to yes but it's still inserting the extra blank entry underneath the actual submitted entry.

Comment: I suggest you use a if condition to check for nulls. 

`if($joined != '' && $uname != '' && $email != '')` 

before your insert query. I am pretty certain it is a redirect to your page without the POST vars that is causing the blank values. Check your http access logs to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to mention the id as blank as the query automatically fetches the id which is defined as primary key and auto increment.You query should like this and after the tablename you can also specify the column name from the database:

```
$sql=mysql_query("insert into `table`(joined,uname,column) values('$joined','$uname','$email')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use validation in your form to fix duplicate date in the database.You use the id field in your form so definitely you should use of javascript.